# Meteor.startup with external react routes component

Tags: meteor, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement Meteor.startup with a Router React component (that lives in a different .jsx) however it doesn't seem to work.

If I have the Router React component in the same .jsx file as Meteor.startup, then it works fine.

Any ideas why this might be?

Here is my code that doesn't work :

```
import { Routes } from './routes.jsx'; 

Meteor.startup( () => {
    render(<Routes />, document.body);
});
```

Please note that routes.jsx contains the same Route as the one shown in the code snippet below.

And here is the code that works :

```
export default class Routes extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        </Route>
      </Router>
      );
  } 
}

Meteor.startup( () => {
      render(<Routes />, document.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you solved this issue, but it most likely has to do with the order your files are loaded. Try putting the `routes.jsx` file in a directory named `imports` instead of the `client` at the root level